# Error al enviar petición a un web service vía SOAP en PHP FACTURA ELECTRÓNICA DIAN

Tags: php, webservice, wsdl

Este es mi código para la validación y envío del archivo en formato .zip, en el elemento  no tiene el código cifrado pero si está funcionando bien

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
   <soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>9a520d45-e94d-4d3d-b671-71822f81c70d</wsse:Username> 
        <wsse:Password>566746bc5f1a87ed9d633ee3efc765bb314f72f4cc65ce022d0acb02b3d8111f</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">MTAxNTAyMzI0NA==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2018-07-20T10:49:20.623Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <rep:EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion>
     <rep:NIT>890200900</rep:NIT>
     <rep:InvoiceNumber>PRUE980000000</rep:InvoiceNumber>
     <rep:IssueDate>2018-07-20T10:49:20</rep:IssueDate>
     <rep:Document></rep:Document>
  </rep:EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

//pero me está mostrando un error 
    
   
   
   JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4 - JBWEB000064: Error report

## JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 400 -

**JBWEB000309: type** JBWEB000067: Status report

**JBWEB000068: message**

**JBWEB000069: description** 
JBWEB000120: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

#### JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4

Agradecería mucho al que se le haya presentado este mismo inconveniente, creo que los datos de validación están bien..igual tenía una pregunta ya que no sé si es obligatorio tener una firma digital para el periodo de pruebas.

Gracias

Comment: a mi me sale el mismo error alguien tiene una respuesta

Comment: El xml que envias a la DIAN, no tiene un formato valido falta el namespace wsu xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"

Comment: jjperez89 Muchas gracias por su respuesta, ahora me está arrojando el siguiente mensaje: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized; nested exception is org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized, eso quiere decir que mis datos como user y password están erróneos y no puede acceder al webservice de la DIAN? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El **wsse:Security** tiene un pequeño error semantico en la URL de **xmlns:wsse**,
 la linea correcta es la siguiente:

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
```